# Declaring multiple relayjs connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, relayjs, graphql-js

I have to two GraphQLObjectType

```
const AType = new GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'A'
fields: () => ({
    id: globalIdField('A', obj => obj._id),
    Id: {
        type: GraphQLID,
        resolve: obj => obj._id
    },
    email: { type: GraphQLString },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    status: { type: GraphQLString },
    description: { type: GraphQLString }
}),
interfaces: [nodeInterface]
});
```

and another Type BType, i am using AType inside the type of so t

```
const BType = new GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'BType',
fields: {
    id: globalIdField('BType'),
     ApplicantsDetails: {
        type: AType,
        resolve: obj => {
            return obj.applicantsId;
        }
    },
    respo_2: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        resolve: obj => "I have declared a ObjectType inside another"
    }
},
 interfaces: [nodeInterface]
});
```

and the main type from where i am returning a promise, so when i return the promise resolve(d), it should go to the BType and

```
const { connectionType: EmployerDashBoardConnectionType} =
connectionDefinitions({
    name: 'EmployerDash',
    nodeType: BType
});
```

above is the connection

```
        EmployerDashBoardConnection: {
        type: EmployerDashBoardConnectionType,
        description: 'Employer DashBoard Details',
        args: connectionArgsWithJobId,
        resolve: (_, args, auth) => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    Dash(_, args, auth, function (err, d) {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err);
                        } else {
                            resolve(d);
                        }
                    });
                });
        }
    }
    /* Introduce your new fields here */
}
```

the response from Dash() function call is

```
 {
   applicantsId: 
   { _id: 5878548b51179817f48eb1f1,
   email: '123@gmail.com',
   password: '$2a$10$lDpfl7kL4i/8VPij8aypmeeiD1794g1afACUxca397LdlErMgWa.S',
 __v: 0,
 name: 'Alpaina',
 status: 'Unemployed',
 isJobSeeker: true,
 to: 2017-01-13T04:16:11.755Z }
 }
```

it only prints null

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for using edges you need to pass an array to resolve function

```
resolve: (_, args, auth) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Dash(_, args, auth, function (err, d) {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        } else {
              // if d is object then 
              const a = [];
              a.push(d);
            resolve(connectionFromArray(a, args));
        }
    });
  });
}
```

this code is to only solve your current problem

*NOTE*: while using relay connections you should always resolve a list `[ ]`

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code:

### First problem:

The node type of `EmployerDashBoardConnectionType` is `BType`. So, the items returned in resolve() function of field `EmployerDashBoardConnection` should have the same properties - that's not the case in your code.

The structure of `BType` is:

```
{
    id
    ApplicantsDetails {
        id,
        Id,
        email,
        name,
        status,
        description,
    }
    respo_2,
}
```

whereas you are passing the following object, which totally does not match.

```
{
    applicantsId: {
        _id: 5878548b51179817f48eb1f1,
        email: '123@gmail.com',
        password: '$2a$10$lDpfl7kL4i/8VPij8aypmeeiD1794g1afACUxca397LdlErMgWa.S',
        __v: 0,
        name: 'Alpaina',
        status: 'Unemployed',
        isJobSeeker: true,
        to: 2017-01-13T04:16:11.755Z
    }
}
```

### Second problem:

This is why you're getting null for edges. Your resolve() function:

```
resolve: (_, args, auth) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Dash(_, args, auth, function (err, d) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(d);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

where you return nothing. You can use `connectionFromArray` from `graphql-relay` npm module:

```
resolve: (_, args, auth) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Dash(_, args, auth, function (err, d) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(connectionFromArray(d, args));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The value of `d` must be a list where each item should have top level properties `id`, `ApplicantsDetails`, `respo_2`.

Comment: In AType it was like some kind of Typing mistake, now i have corrected it.,

The Dash() is returning a promise object with data's, but also graphql is giving null,
when i use connectionFromArray it gives `arraySlice.slice` is not a function

Comment: i think if you are doing connections, then your data type should be an array

Comment: @terik_poe, I have updated my answer. The return value `d` of Dash function must be a list where each item must have a structure similar to BType.